# jquery - select images - than copy selected images "href" elements

Tags: jquery, html

My page loads a lot of images in the next format:

```html
<a class="something" href="1.html">
     <div class="something">
        <img alt="name" src="https://www.homepage.com/.1.jpg"/>
     </div>
</a>
```

How can I select, with jQuery, the images I want, and after clicking the "copy" button force it to copy the `href` attributes from all selected images together to clipboard, or to an input box in format:

```
http://www.homepage.com/1.html
http://www.homepage.com/7.html
http://www.homepage.com/15.html
http://www.homepage.com/21.html
```

Depending on which images I select.

Thank you, and sorry for bad English.

Comment: NOTE: i must put - instead of .  in the links because i cant write more than 2 links with my reputation. Sorry fot that!

Comment: what copy button are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take would be to add a 'selected' class to each selected image when the user clicks it. From there, you can query the page for $('.selected') when the user clicks your "copy" button.

It's worth pointing out that at this time, there are few and limited solutions for copying content to a user's clipboard. 
The classic solution has been using a dynamically generated Flash Movie Clip, but that solution is pretty clunky and won't work on any devices that don't have flash (like all iPhones, iPads, most "smart" TVs and similar hardware, etc).
There are a few new alternatives like (https://clipboardjs.com), but they have relatively limited browser support - and only for modern browsers.

Your best solution might be to take all of the href attributes you collect and just write them to a `<div>` or to a `<textarea>`.

You will probably get more help and more specific help if you post the javascript/jQuery you've tried so far.

Comment: @Edwin    D  I didnt try anything actually with the code. Ok i dont need to use "copytoclipboard option" I can use option to copy all those links into the textarea, and i can manually copy it   If you want to see what the html code look like please check my answer below.

Comment: Why don't you try writing some code and then come back and ask if you still need help?

Comment: I just did, i answered on this topic with jsfiddle snipped. Thank you. Must say that there is actually no jquery code at all in the snipped because i am not able to write it.

Comment: That's what I was suggesting you try writing. Here's a very beginner-level jQuery tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp --- I would also recommend that you get rid of all of the classes and IDs like `_8mlbc` and `_icyx7`. These things don't have any implicit meaning, so it's very easy to make mistakes and makes it very hard to read.

Comment: i relly tried but its impossible at the moment for me to get what i want, i know only basics but thank you. btw those classes and IDs are Instagram classes and ids. I am not able to change that. I usually use somehting simple.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6966/

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  
});
```

```css
._myci9 {
    padding: 5px;
}

._22yr2 {
    widht:auto;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin:5px;
}

._22yr2 img {
    width: 110px;
    float:left;
    height:110px;
    
}

._ovg3g {
    clear:both;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 20em
}

p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="_myci9">
   <a class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b" href="/p/BRB4zUeBnYk/?taken-by=kingjames">
      <div class="_22yr2">
         <img alt="something" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_32" src="https://instagram.flju2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/16906087_242760049518775_800349524768849920_n.jpg">
      </div>
   </a>
   <a class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b" href="/p/BQvr-9_BE6S/?taken-by=kingjames">
      <div class="_22yr2">
        <img alt="something" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_33" src="https://instagram.flju2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/e35/c143.0.409.409/16789700_731933080314257_4953666797892009984_n.jpg">
         
        
      </div>
   </a>
   <a class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b" href="/p/BQqSt9TBmk2/?taken-by=kingjames">
      <div class="_22yr2">
        <img alt="something" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_34" src="https://instagram.flju2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.64.618.618/16789715_173474169818953_8577321114865238016_n.jpg">
        
      </div>
   </a>
    <div class="_ovg3g"></div>
   <a class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b" href="/p/BQogu-ihCIr/?taken-by=kingjames">
      <div class="_22yr2">
        <img alt="something" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_24" src="https://instagram.flju2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/16789375_683901995123878_4667158291309133824_n.jpg">
        
      </div>
   </a>
   <a class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b" href="/p/BQi3qtjFnR7/?taken-by=kingjames">
      <div class="_22yr2">
        <img alt="something" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_25" src="https://instagram.flju2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/16465687_1404916892863742_734096368578068480_n.jpg">
         
      </div>
   </a>
   <a class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b" href="/p/BQgbFZbFLeM/?taken-by=kingjames">
      <div class="_22yr2">
       <img alt="something" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_26" src="https://instagram.flju2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c0.75.851.851/16465085_1795837224074827_2439164261574901760_n.jpg">
       
      </div>
   </a> 
   <div class="_ovg3g"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button  id="copybtn" type="button">Click to copy</button>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
place to copy links in
</textarea>
```

This is what i currntly have. I really hope that u can understand what my idea is. Dont care about css, it desnt matter right now.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/kmgzbnmh/

```js
$('a').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  var urlToCopy = $(this).attr('href') + '<br>';
  $('.listbox').append(urlToCopy);
})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.listbox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="something" href="http://www.faykew3bsite.comm/1.html">
     <div class="something">
        <img alt="name" src="http://i.imgur.com/1T9xqzR.jpg">
     </div>
</a>
<a class="something" href="http://www.faykew3bsite.comm/2.html">
     <div class="something">
        <img alt="name" src="http://i.imgur.com/SyhkvcN.jpg">
     </div>
</a>
<a class="something" href="http://www.faykew3bsite.comm/3.html">
     <div class="something">
        <img alt="name" src="http://i.imgur.com/9Qjz8RE.jpg">
     </div>
</a>

<div class="listbox"></div>
```